# Running a Bash command on files with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm creating  a script that needs to go through all the files on a server and run each of those files names followed by the command "ll" and then take the output of that command and print it to a txt file.

example:

folder/filename.txt ll

output: SoMETHINGSomethingSomethingother - This is sent to a output.txt file

folder/subfolder/filename3.txt ll

output: SoMETHINGSomethingSomethingother - This is sent to a output.txt file

This is what I have so far:

```
import os

with open("output.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test_Py'):
       for filename in files:
         f = os.path.join(filename)
         m = f + ' ll'

         a.write(str(m) + os.linesep)
```

So what I'm trying to figure out now is how to make the file names that are printed out run with the "ll" command. So far this code will write the names of all the files in that folder and its subfolders in to my output.txt file.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: check `subprocess` module http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running shell command from python and capturing the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: It's worth noting that in Perl you can write to a pipeline by opening the file (eg `open(my $pipeline, "| command | command > file");`), but Python doesn't allow this.

Comment: @Eliot. Python performs that function. It would be odd if Python used the same syntax as Perl don't you think?

Comment: @Paddy3118 yes, I'm just pointing out for general knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.system()`:

```
import os

with open("output.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test_Py'):
        for filename in files:
            f = os.path.join(filename)
            m = f + ' ll > output.txt'

            os.system(m)
```

This will send only the standard output to the `output.txt` file. If you want to send error messages to `output.txt` as well, use `m = f + ' ll > output.txt 2>&1'` instead.

Explanation: `os.system(command_string)` will execute the command `command_string` in your system as if you typed that command into a terminal. The `>` operator is standard in Windows and Linux to redirect standard output from a command into a file. The `2>&1` extra argument at the end is the only not-so-clear part: it redirects standard error to the same place where standard output is going. See more about this last part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21).

Comment: Well it turns out I can't test this out until Thursday but I want to first say thank you for answering. I believe this will work. Also thank you for explaining it its really helped. Once I check on Thursday I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: We should replace `os.system` calls by their `subprocess` counterparts. Therefore a downvote.

Comment: @user1636295: `subprocess` is more general than `os.system`. However, `os.system` is not being deprecated, so there's no big problem in using it, even though the Python docs suggest [1] that people use `subprocess`. You can replace the `os.system(m)` line with `subprocess.call(m,shell=True)` [1]. I prefer `system` for these cases because it is less verbose.  

[1]http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the files with the "ll" command you can use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module available in python.

Your revised code will be:-

```
import os
import subprocess
import shlex

with open("output.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test_Py'):
       for filename in files:
         f = os.path.join(filename)
         m = f + ' ll'

         cmd_args = shlex.split(m)
         output = subprocess.check_output(cmd_args)
         a.write(output + os.linesep)
```